# Cannot figure out format needed to make predictions on dataset trained with doc2vec and random forest classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, doc2vec

I am trying to make predictions on a dataset based on some pre-defined data (tweets and categories that the tweets belong to, labeled 1-16) that I have built a model in with doc2vec and trained on random forest classifier. I am confused about what format I need to put my data into before I call `clf.predict(tweet)` on it.

```
import csv
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from gensim import utils
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
import gensim  
import numpy as np

#just making the object to put into gensim's doc2vec
class LabeledLineSentence(object):

    def __init__(self, doc_list, labels_list):
            self.labels_list = labels_list
            self.doc_list = doc_list

    def __iter__(self):
            for t, l in itertools.izip(self.doc_list, self.labels_list):
                    #change here
                    t = nltk.word_tokenize(t)
                    #end of change
                    yield gensim.models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(t, [l])

#predefined
tweets = ["a tweet", "another tweet", ... , "a thousandth tweet"]
labels = [1, 1, ... , 16] #what category the tweet belongs to

training_data = LabeledLineSentence(tweets, labels_list)

#build the doc2vec model
model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, min_count=1, dm=1)
model.build_vocab(training_data)
model.train(training_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=20)

#put tweets into classifier
train_tweets = []

for i in range(len(tweets)):
    label = labels_list[i]
    train_tweets.append(model[label])

#have to convert to numpy array because that is what clf takes
train_tweets = np.array(train_tweets)
train_labels = np.array(labels_list)

#fit classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(train_tweets, train_labels)


#this is the data i am trying to classify into labels
test_data = ["an unseen tweet", "another unseen tweet", ... , "a thousandth unseen tweet"]

#*******change here***************
for t in test_data:
    split = nltk.word_tokenize(t)
    vect = model.infer_vector(split)
    vect = vect.reshape(1, -1)
    print clf.predict(vect)
```

Towards the end of this code block is where I am getting confused. I am pretty sure I built the doc2vec model and trained the classifier right, but I am unsure of what I need to do to each tweet in the testing data before I call `clf.predict` on it. I have tried tokenizing the string and using a count vectorizer, but I keep getting errors about how it cannot convert those to a float. Is there some other way I am supposed to process the test data before putting it in for prediction?

Comment: You should grab a working RandomForestClassifier examples from scikit-learn docs/tutorials to build upon - and keep in mind it will want an array of purely-numeric datapoints ('X') and results ('y') for its `fit()` step. Hard to say more there until you've tried more. But you're doing `Doc2Vec` wrong. Don't change the default `alpha` values. Don't call `train()` more than once unless you absolutely need to (and you don't).

Comment: Also: a `min_count` that throws away rare words (rather than keeping all like `min_count=0`) usually improves results. An `epochs` of 10-20 is most common in published work, though more may be helpful with undersized datasets. And, if you do have a small dataset, you may have to use a smaller `vector_size`.

Comment: @gojomo Thank you for your suggestions on doc2vec. I have updated accordingly. As for the examples on RFC, I based my code on [this example](http://linanqiu.github.io/2015/10/07/word2vec-sentiment/) (about 3/4 of the way down) to try and figure out how to transfer the model I created to RFC and put it into `fit()` .

Comment: Also it looks like the training-texts you're constructing in your `LabeledLineSentence` class will have a `words` property that's text strings - when it's supposed to be a list-of-word-tokens.

Comment: After that's fixed, what is the `t` in `test_data`? The classifier needs numeric inputs that are just like the `X` input-data it was `fit()` on. So if `t` is a raw text string, it'll need to be tokenized to a list-of-tokens the same as training-data was, then that list-of-tokens turned into a fixed-length vector similar to the `model[label]` training-vectors. (See `infer_vector()` for how `Doc2Vec` can create vectors for post-training texts.) Only then can that fixed-length vector be an input to the clasifier's `predict()`.

Comment: @gojomo Thank you for pointing that out in `LabeledLineSentence`. I have tokenized it with `nltk.word_tokenize()` (I updated it in the post as well). Does this look good? I have also tried something at the bottom of the code block (which I also updated in the post): splitting the string into tokens, using `infer_vector()`, and reshaping the vector. It seems to be running, but everytime I run it, I get different results from `print clf.predict(vect)`. Is this normal or do you have an idea why it might not be?

Comment: Calling `predict()` repeatedly on exactly the same `vect` should give the same result. But, the other steps use randomness and thus aren't necessarily deterministic: each Doc2Vec training (even on same data) can give different results, each inference, each `fit()`. You should sanity-check each step, with logging on: do the training-set doc-vectors seem to make sense (via `most_similar()` checks) on their own? Does inferring a new text & then checking for similars in the training set give sensible results? etc.

Comment: Also, `Doc2Vec` benefits from a lot of data... and if you've been able to rerun the whole pipeline in the last ~30m, you may not be working with much. Published `Doc2Vec` results tend to use at least tens-of-thousands, but often millions, of distinct texts, each of dozens to hundreds/thousands of words long. Don't expect good results with toy-sized data.

Comment: Yes, my dataset is rather small in comparison to what you just described. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your help!